# Send a message in to the teams channel using extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am looking for a solution where I could send the message to the team of **which I am not a member** of using Microsoft Teams Extension.

So, I know if I am not part of the I cannot send it personally from my side. But **a bot can do that.**

So, **how I can send the message from the Extension to Bot and Bot will send this to the channel?**

**Side note**: I am able to initiate the thread in the channel using the bot, following the code structure from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/58.teams-start-new-thread-in-channel

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about the extension you mentioned? Is it a webhook?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, I have figured put the way will post the answers in a bit.